# Set focus on input - React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, redux, react-redux

I have a react component which has a input field with disable attribute. On click of the component, the input gets enabled and user can type on the field. I'm able to achieve till there, but I need to focus on input field on getting enabled.

Attributes.js

```
basicAmenitiesList.map(function(item, index){
     return <Attribute key={index} 
                       name={item.amenity_id} 
                       type={item.title} 
                       icon={item.icon} 
                       selected={item.isSelected} 
                       value={item.value} 
                       onClick={_this.handleClick.bind(this)} 
                       onChange={_this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
})
```

The Attribute file :

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
...
       <input type="text" name={this.props.name}
              ref={this.props.name}
              placeholder="NO INFO FOUND"
              value={this.props.value}
              disabled={!this.props.selected}
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
       />
</div>

handleClick(e) {
    // I need to focus on enabling., that is when **this.props.selected** is true.
    return this.props.onClick(this.props.name);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried onFocus for input,

```
onFocus(){
    this.refs.pets.focus();
}
```

Right now I'm hard coding the refs name as *pets*, but is there any way to make it dynamic by sending the name with the onFocus?

Answer (score 1):

you can use autoFocus as property for input

```
<input type="text" name={this.props.name}
              ref={this.props.name}
              placeholder="NO INFO FOUND"
              value={this.props.value}
              disabled={!this.props.selected}
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
              autoFocus
       />
```

Comment: I have the same problem and unfortunately, autofocus property is not an option in my case (possible multiple, nested / hidden inputs)